# Separating explode array from URL string

Tags: php, curl

I'm using BulkSMS which is a SMS service and I want to get how many messages I have left using the URL response.

This is the URL (with password removed):
`https://www.bulksms.co.uk/eapi/user/get_credits/1/1.1?username=<username>&password=<password>`

This then outputs something similar to:
`0|2000.00`

According to the [documentation](http://developer.bulksms.com/eapi/account/get_credits/) the first part refers to error messages and the second part refers to no. of messages remaining: `status_code|status_description`

So using `cURL` and `explode` I can get the URL response split via an array, but my question is how do I output the `2000.00 (status_description)` as I would only want the `0 (status_code)` for error checking?

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $array = explode('|', $data);
    print_r($array);
}
```

If it helps this is what the function outputs:
`Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 2000.00 )`

Also I know I could use `substr` and `strpos` to get the remaining messages as shown below, but I would like to use the `status_code` for error checking.

```
$remaining_sms = substr($data, strpos($data, "|") + 1);    
echo $remaining_sms;
```

Comment: Ummm... `echo $array[0];` and `echo $array[1];`

Comment: Ha well I feel stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the second part of the pipe delimited message then just return that part of the array, given you know the index...

This will output what you want

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $array = explode('|', $data);
    print_r($array[1]);
}
```

Or alternatively you could return it and then parse it in your code later

```
function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $array = explode('|', $data);
        return $array;
    }
```

Either way I don't get why you're substring-ing when you've already gotten it